# Multi-Level Table From Pandas Dataframe Using PYQT5

Tags: pandas, pyqt5

I am relatively new to python. I am busy building a GUI with multiple widgets. One of the widgets is a multi-level table. The levels are column-wise and categorise shares/stocks into sectors and industries. The subsequent columns display some fundamental data such as earnings, dividends, financial ratios, etc. One column of the table is reserved for user input that needs to be saved locally.

I have tried using the solution below. The table works well. However, the table opens outside of my GUI. I’m not sure where to change the parent in the solution code to show the table inside the.

https://github.com/adamerose/PandasGUI/blob/cded504a806cb41b37f77734b8c4f840829a9827/pandasgui/widgets/dataframe_viewer.py

In the code that follows, the widget that will hold the table as well as a save button in my GUI is
self.Screen = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.Screen.setObjectName("Screen")

I would like the solution code to add the multilevel table to this widget instead of an entirely new window (shown in the attached picture).
Please see code below:

[It currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLk6m.jpg)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import QCustomSlideMenu, QCustomStackedWidget
import resources_rc
from IntegrateCalcs import SIMScreen
from Table import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(879, 563)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("*{\n"
"border:none;\n"
"background-color:transparent;\n"
"background:none;\n"
"padding:0;\n"
"margin:0;\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(31, 35, 42);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.leftMenuContainer = QCustomSlideMenu(self.centralwidget)
        self.leftMenuContainer.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
        self.leftMenuContainer.setObjectName("leftMenuContainer")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.leftMenuContainer)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.leftMenuSubContainer = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.leftMenuContainer)
        self.leftMenuSubContainer.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(22, 25, 29);\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"text-align: left;\n"
"padding: 2px 5px\n"
"")
        self.leftMenuSubContainer.setObjectName("leftMenuSubContainer")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.leftMenuSubContainer)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(5, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.leftMenuSubContainer)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.Integrate_Logo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.Integrate_Logo.setStyleSheet("font: 700 12pt \"Segoe UI\";\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"color: rgb(30, 109, 255);")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/menu.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.Integrate_Logo.setIcon(icon)
        self.Integrate_Logo.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        self.Integrate_Logo.setObjectName("Integrate_Logo")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Integrate_Logo)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.leftMenuSubContainer)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.TradeBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        self.TradeBtn.setFont(font)
        self.TradeBtn.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.TradeBtn.setStyleSheet("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/refresh-ccw.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.TradeBtn.setIcon(icon1)
        self.TradeBtn.setDefault(False)
        self.TradeBtn.setFlat(False)
        self.TradeBtn.setObjectName("TradeBtn")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.TradeBtn)
        self.PortfolioAnalysisBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/pie-chart.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.PortfolioAnalysisBtn.setIcon(icon2)
        self.PortfolioAnalysisBtn.setObjectName("PortfolioAnalysisBtn")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.PortfolioAnalysisBtn)
        self.BetAlignBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/sliders.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.BetAlignBtn.setIcon(icon3)
        self.BetAlignBtn.setObjectName("BetAlignBtn")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.BetAlignBtn)
        self.ScreenBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/monitor.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.ScreenBtn.setIcon(icon4)
        self.ScreenBtn.setObjectName("ScreenBtn")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.ScreenBtn)
        self.ForecastsBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/target.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.ForecastsBtn.setIcon(icon5)
        self.ForecastsBtn.setObjectName("ForecastsBtn")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.ForecastsBtn)
        self.BusinessRiskBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/alert-triangle.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.BusinessRiskBtn.setIcon(icon6)
        self.BusinessRiskBtn.setObjectName("BusinessRiskBtn")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.BusinessRiskBtn)
        self.AnalystsBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        icon7 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon7.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/users.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.AnalystsBtn.setIcon(icon7)
        self.AnalystsBtn.setObjectName("AnalystsBtn")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.AnalystsBtn)
        self.ESGBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        icon8 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon8.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/slack.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.ESGBtn.setIcon(icon8)
        self.ESGBtn.setObjectName("ESGBtn")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.ESGBtn)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_2, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.leftMenuSubContainer)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_3, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.leftMenuSubContainer)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.leftMenuContainer, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.mainBodyContainer = QCustomSlideMenu(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.mainBodyContainer.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.mainBodyContainer.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.mainBodyContainer.setObjectName("mainBodyContainer")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.mainBodyContainer)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.headerContainer = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.mainBodyContainer)
        self.headerContainer.setObjectName("headerContainer")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.headerContainer)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.Controls = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.headerContainer)
        self.Controls.setStyleSheet("")
        self.Controls.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.Controls.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Controls.setObjectName("Controls")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Controls)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.MinimiseBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Controls)
        self.MinimiseBtn.setStyleSheet("")
        self.MinimiseBtn.setText("")
        icon9 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon9.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/minus.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.MinimiseBtn.setIcon(icon9)
        self.MinimiseBtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 12))
        self.MinimiseBtn.setObjectName("MinimiseBtn")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.MinimiseBtn)
        self.MaximiseBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Controls)
        self.MaximiseBtn.setStyleSheet("")
        self.MaximiseBtn.setText("")
        icon10 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon10.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons SIM Blue/Icons SIM Blue/maximize-2.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.MaximiseBtn.setIcon(icon10)
        self.MaximiseBtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 12))
        self.MaximiseBtn.setObjectName("MaximiseBtn")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.MaximiseBtn)
        self.ExitBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Controls)
        self.ExitBtn.setStyleSheet("")
        self.ExitBtn.setText("")
        icon11 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon11.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Icons Red/Icons Red/x-circle.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.ExitBtn.setIcon(icon11)
        self.ExitBtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 12))
        self.ExitBtn.setObjectName("ExitBtn")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.ExitBtn)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.Controls, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.headerContainer, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.mainContentsContainer = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.mainBodyContainer)
        self.mainContentsContainer.setObjectName("mainContentsContainer")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.mainContentsContainer)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.mainPages = QCustomStackedWidget(self.mainContentsContainer)
        self.mainPages.setObjectName("mainPages")
        self.Trade = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Trade.setObjectName("Trade")
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.Trade)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName("verticalLayout_9")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Trade)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.mainPages.addWidget(self.Trade)
        self.PortfolioAnalysis = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.PortfolioAnalysis.setObjectName("PortfolioAnalysis")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.PortfolioAnalysis)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.PortfolioAnalysis)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.mainPages.addWidget(self.PortfolioAnalysis)
        self.BetAlign = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.BetAlign.setObjectName("BetAlign")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.BetAlign)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.BetAlign)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_5, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.mainPages.addWidget(self.BetAlign)
        self.Screen = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Screen.setObjectName("Screen")
        self.mainPages.addWidget(self.Screen)
        self.Forecasts = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Forecasts.setObjectName("Forecasts")
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Forecasts)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Forecasts)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.label_8, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.mainPages.addWidget(self.Forecasts)
        self.BusinessRisk = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.BusinessRisk.setObjectName("BusinessRisk")
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.BusinessRisk)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.BusinessRisk)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_6, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.mainPages.addWidget(self.BusinessRisk)
        self.Analysts = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Analysts.setObjectName("Analysts")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Analysts)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Analysts)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.mainPages.addWidget(self.Analysts)
        self.ESG = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ESG.setObjectName("ESG")
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.ESG)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.ESG)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label_7, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.mainPages.addWidget(self.ESG)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.mainPages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.mainContentsContainer)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.mainBodyContainer)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.ScreenBtn.clicked.connect(self.ScreenTable)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.mainPages.setCurrentIndex(3)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def ScreenTable(self,):
        Screen = DataFrameViewer(SIMScreen())
        Screen.show()




    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Integrate_Logo.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu"))
        self.Integrate_Logo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "INTEGR∞"))
        self.TradeBtn.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Trade"))
        self.TradeBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Trade"))
        self.PortfolioAnalysisBtn.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Portfolio Analysis"))
        self.PortfolioAnalysisBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Portfolio Analysis"))
        self.BetAlignBtn.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Bet Alignment"))
        self.BetAlignBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Bet Alignment"))
        self.ScreenBtn.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Screen Securities"))
        self.ScreenBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Screen"))
        self.ForecastsBtn.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Analyst Forecasts"))
        self.ForecastsBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Forecasts"))
        self.BusinessRiskBtn.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Business Risk Rating"))
        self.BusinessRiskBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Business Risk"))
        self.AnalystsBtn.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Analyst Recommendations Performance"))
        self.AnalystsBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Analysts"))
        self.ESGBtn.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "ESG Rating"))
        self.ESGBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " ESG"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Trade"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Portfolio Analysis"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Model Bet Alignment"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Forecast Tool"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Business Risk Rating"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Analysts"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ESG"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You should set a layout for that `self.Screen` widget and add the other widget to that layout. Note that you're **not** expected to edit pyuic files, so please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: I have tried that, but then when I click the self.ScreenBtn to run the Table, the app terminates. I read on the web that it may be due to the fact the table itself doesn't have a parent, it is created outside of the UI. So when you add to the layout it bombs the UI.

Comment: The fact that the table doesn't have a parent won't make the app crash. Please provide the code of those attempts.

Comment: Thank you @musicamante, adding it to the layout worked! I was being a bit silly :)